# Am getting this error; EJBCLIENT000025: No EJB receiver available for handling

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly

I have been racking my brain and turning google upside down but can't find solution to this problem. Am using netbeans 8.1 and wildfly 10 server
This is my Client class:

```
public class EjbTester {
    BufferedReader brConsoleReader = null;
    Properties props;
    InitialContext ctx;
    Context remoteContext;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    EjbTester ejbtester = new EjbTester();
    ejbtester.tasteStatelessEJB();
}

private void tasteStatelessEJB(){
     try{
        props = new Properties();
        props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
        props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://localhost:8050");
        props.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
        props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "steinacoz");
        props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "nkenna007");
        props.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);

        ctx = new InitialContext(props);

    }catch(NamingException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

brConsoleReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    try{
        int choice = 1;
        LibrarySessionBeanRemote libraryBean = (LibrarySessionBeanRemote) ctx.lookup("ejb:/EJBtut/LibrarySessionBean!tut.LibrarySessionBeanRemote");
        while(choice != 2){
            String bookName;

            String strChoice = brConsoleReader.readLine();
            choice = Integer.parseInt(strChoice);
            if(choice == 1){
                System.out.println("Enter Book Name: ");
                bookName = brConsoleReader.readLine();
                libraryBean.addBook(bookName);
            }else if(choice == 2){
                break;
            }
        }

        List<String> booksList = libraryBean.getBooks();
        System.out.println("Books entered so far: " + booksList.size());

        for(int i = 0; i < booksList.size(); i++){
            System.out.print((i+1) + "." + booksList.get(i));
        }
       ctx.close();

      LibrarySessionBeanRemote libraryBean1 = (LibrarySessionBeanRemote) ctx.lookup("ejb:/EJBtut/LibrarySessionBean!tut.LibrarySessionBeanRemote");     
     List<String> booksList1 = libraryBean.getBooks();
     System.out.print("---using lookups to get library stateless objects--");
     System.out.print("Books Entered so far: " + booksList1.size());

       for(int i = 0; i < booksList1.size(); i++){
            System.out.print((i+1) + "." + booksList1.get(i));
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try{
            if(brConsoleReader != null){
                brConsoleReader.close();
            }
        }catch(IOException ex){
             System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace(); 
        }
    }
}


   }
```

This is my remote interface

```
@Remote
public interface LibrarySessionBeanRemote {
 void addBook (String book);

List getBooks();

 }
```

This is my SessionBean

```
@Stateless
public class LibrarySessionBean implements LibrarySessionBeanRemote{
List<String> bookShelf;

public LibrarySessionBean() {
    bookShelf = new ArrayList<String>();
}


public void addBook(String bookName) {
bookShelf.add(bookName);
}

public List<String> getBooks() {
return bookShelf;
}
}
```

This is the error i have been encountering, Some should please help

> EJBCLIENT000025: No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:, moduleName:EJBtut, distinctName:] combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@100fc185
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: EJBCLIENT000025: No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:, moduleName:EJBtut, distinctName:] combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@100fc185
>       at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireEJBReceiver(EJBClientContext.java:798)
>       at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:128)
>       at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:186)
>       at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.sendRequestWithPossibleRetries(EJBInvocationHandler.java:255)
>       at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:200)
>       at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:183)
>       at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:146)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.addBook(Unknown Source)
>       at client.EjbTester.tasteStatelessEJB(EjbTester.java:80)
>       at client.EjbTester.main(EjbTester.java:46)

Comment: I'd start by double checking the jndi url you are using. Also check server.log as that normally gives information about services binding and the jndi path

Comment: I have solved the issue,  I edited the jndi name and removed ejb:/ from it. LibrarySessionBeanRemote libraryBean = (LibrarySessionBeanRemote) ctx.lookup("ejb:/EJBtut/LibrarySessionBean!tut.LibrarySessionBeanRemote");